# Cannot save associated data with hasMany through (Join Model)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Hi, I am new to cakephp and doing a project on cakephp 2.3.4.
I have to associate product metal class through has many through association . But it doesn't seem to be working.

**Model code**

```
class Metal extends AppModel {
public $hasMany = array(
  'MetalProduct'
 );
}

class Product extends AppModel {
public $hasMany = array(
  'MetalProduct'
 );
}

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class MetalProduct extends AppModel {

public $belongsTo = array(
    'Metal' => array(
        'className'    => 'Metal',
        'foreignKey'   => 'metal_id'
    ),
   'Product' => array(
        'className'    => 'Product',
        'foreignKey'   => 'product_id'
    )
);}
```

My database table names are **metal**, **products** and **metal_products**

I have multiple select option for selecting more than one metal type.
This is how I get the the list of metals

```
     $metals=$this->Metal->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('metals'));
```

FormHelper code for listbox is

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Metal',array('type' => 'select', 
                                                'multiple' => true)); ?>
```

The product is getting saved successfully but the associations are not.
The debug array give me this

```
    $message = array(
'Product' => array(
    'category_id' => '517a514b-0eb0-4ec9-b018-0b948620d4f0',
    'name' => 'mangalsutra Diamond',
    'slug' => 'mangalsutra_diamond',
    'description' => '1212',
    'Metal' => array(
        (int) 0 => '5183cb65-bf90-459c-b22e-0b748620d4f0',
        (int) 1 => '5183ce25-c744-433e-b035-0b748620d4f0'
    ),
    'image' => '121212',
    'price' => '12121',
    'weight' => '12',
    'active' => '1',
    'category' => 'Mangalsutra'
)
 )
```

I had put my head through walls but no clue why the associations are not getting saved.
The way they say in tutorials it seems easy, but why its not working?

I have doubts that its not saving because the metal array is passed like this

```
    'Metal' => array(
        (int) 0 => '5183cb65-bf90-459c-b22e-0b748620d4f0',
        (int) 1 => '5183ce25-c744-433e-b035-0b748620d4f0'
    ),
```

It should mention 'id''rather than (int) 0 or something.

Also, my database table for metal_products which I have created manually has

```
  id(primary key)
  metal_id(foreign key to Metal.id)
  product_id(foreign key to Product.id)
```

Am I doing something wrong with naming conventions or the way database is created? 
Please give me  correct ans cause anything I tried from others answer is not working

I am saving it via

```
     $this->Product->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true))
```

Comment: Do you mean 2.3.4? CakePHP 2.4 is not even a beta/RC yet

Comment: sorry my bad 2.3.4 it is i will correct it

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using hasMany-belongsTo-hasMany association instead of a HABTM?

Comment: As far as I know, the has many relationship need prepared as an array in $this->request->data,can you debug($this->request->data) and check?

Comment: Can you post the html code that `$this->Form->input('Metal',array('type' => 'select', 
                                                'multiple' => true));` is producing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Relation i generated using Bake looks something like this

```
class Product extends AppModel {

 /**
 * hasAndBelongsToMany associations
 */
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Metal' => array(
        'className' => 'Metal',
        'joinTable' => 'metals_products',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'metal_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    ));
}

 class Metal extends AppModel {
 /** hasAndBelongsToMany associations */
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Product' => array(
        'className' => 'Product',
        'joinTable' => 'metals_products',
        'foreignKey' => 'metal_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'product_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    ));
  }

 /**
  * MetalsProduct Model
  * @property Product $Product
  * @property Metal $Metal
  */
  class MetalsProduct extends AppModel {
  /* belongsTo associations */
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Product' => array(
        'className' => 'Product',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Metal' => array(
        'className' => 'Metal',
        'foreignKey' => 'metal_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ));
   }
```

This worked for me flawlessly.
Hope it works for all.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, is all of that in your MetalProduct Model?  If so you need to move

```
class Metal extends AppModel {
public $hasMany = array(
  'MetalProduct'
 );
}
```

to the Metal model and

```
class Product extends AppModel {
public $hasMany = array(
  'MetalProduct'
 );
}
```

to the Product Model

Also add your belongsTo to each Model

I see you have a join table.  Join tables are usually for HABTM associations.  This is a HasMany.  You need to use the other options available to define the foreign key relationships in each model as outlined above.

Please see the examples on the Cake Documentation.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Also, if you are unsure of how to set up the models correctly, you can always use the Bake feature of Cakephp to generate the models and code for you in that regard.

book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html

If you are more of a visual learner this video tut should help you through the basics

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJAMifqF5s8

Comment: My model  has been setup exactly as you suggested also i want hasMany Through association to get working . According to it we just need to create third model MetalProduuct  as explaind in the example http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html       which says one has to create CourseMembership model to get hasMany Through working. It looks so simple i have exactly did the same with my models and created database accordingly. But for some reason its not working . I have already implemented the links you mentioned but nothing seems to work. plz need help

Comment: Finally fixed it . Thanks for you pointer Johnson. I built the database relation first and baked the models using bake. Which defined all the relation in models. Though it was same as i did it somehow after baking models using bake made it work . Only changes i had to made was to product and category relations. Category Model has a tree structure so i had to define the hasmany relation between  category by myself to get generateTreeList working.  I suggest to all cakephp beginners to use bake to generate models and then move forward with the development. Thanks